# Customizing SwiftUI ListView rows

Tags: ios, listview, swiftui

[image: sample]I'm trying to implement a ListView rows laid out in the image where the top static view stretches to end of screen with no padding and no corner radius.

I tried using UIScreen's width but no success

```
Struct MyView: View {

   var body: some View {
      List {
        topStaticView
          .cornerRadius(0)
          .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
       
        bottomView
      }
      .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
   }

}

extension MyView {
   var topStaticView: some View {
      ...
   }

   var bottomView: some View {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Look into `LazyVStack` and `pinnedView` of a `Section`

Comment: Is the question just about the padding around the top view containing the chart? It might help to change the list style from ```insetGrouped``` to ```plain```. If you want to get rid of the inset completely then try changing it from a ```List``` to a ```VStack```.

Comment: I need to remove the padding round the topView but keep the padding on the bottomView.

Comment: @JobieJ So why not use a ```VStack``` with padding around the lower view? Or to ask another way, why does it have to be a ```List```?

Comment: What you are seeing on the `List` row are the `EdgeInsets`. To change them, use `.listRowInsets()`. To remove the insets altogether, you can use `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this question is all about the padding around the top view. The top view consists of a chart and its controls.

To demonstrate the options, I have simplified `topStaticView` and `bottomView` to the following:

```swift
var topStaticView: some View {
    Text("topStaticView")
        .frame(height: 200)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.yellow)
}

var bottomView: some View {
    Text("bottomView")
        .frame(height: 200)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.gray)
}
```

**1. List style insetGrouped**

In the OP, you have applied `.insetGrouped` as list style. With this style, you can reduce the insets by setting `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())`, but it doesn't remove the padding at the side:

```swift
List {
    topStaticView
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    bottomView
}
.listStyle(.insetGrouped)
```

[image: insetGrouoped]

You will notice that the corners of the group section are rounded. Since the top view has no insets, the top corners of the top section have also been rounded.

**2. List style plain**

Now let's try it with `.plain` as list style:

```swift
List {
    topStaticView
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    bottomView
}
.listStyle(.plain)
```

[image: plain]

I think this is now how you wanted it, right? The padding at the side has gone and so have the rounded corners.

**3. A simple VStack**

I was asking in the comments why it needed to be a `List` at all. If it doesn't have to be a `List` then you could just use a simple `VStack` to achieve the same layout, with padding around the `bottomView`. If the content is likely to exceed the height of the display then nest it inside a `ScrollView`:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        topStaticView
        bottomView
            .padding()
    }
}
```

This layout looks almost exactly the same as case 2, see previous screenshot. There are some minor differences in the sizes of the spaces that the padding gives you, but you can control this if you want to by tweaking the padding.